# text and sp / dp, it just does not work nicely

Tags: android

I am testing my app on a Nexus 5 (full HD screen) and an HTC One X (720p).

Using sp as a good Android developer, actually gives me a result I do not want!
The text on the Nexus 5 is bigger than on the HTC One X, even taking into account that the screen is bigger in size.

When I use 'dp' instead of 'sp', they are actually more alike...the result I want...

But you want to use sp, as that is the way you should do it.

So I created a values-sw380dp directory and put there a different value. But, the Nexus 5 does NOT use these values! Then I used this code:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```

Surprisingly: for both phones, the dpWidth == 360! So I have no way to do this nicely for 720p and 1080p screen ?

Does anyone have an idea or solution?

I am tempted to use DP...

Comment: **sp** is correct, for fonts. You might want to try using a [dimension file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) to specify custom sizes.

Comment: But as I stated, it is not possible to differentiate the One X 720p and Nexus 5 1080p screen

Comment: sw720dp and sw1080dp is incorrect! 720 and 1080 is width in pixels. Both phones correspond to the sw360dp values

Comment: Try using **xxhdpi** for the Nexus5 and **xhdpi** for the One X.

Comment: I think you have a point here! I should check density instead of screen size! I will evaluate this this evening and will let you know. If you put this as an answer, I can mark it as correct when verified it